# Notion API Pagination Random Database Entry

Tags: database, random, pagination, notion-api

I'm trying to retrieve a random entry from a database using the Notion API. There is a page limit on how many entries you can retrieve at once, so pagination is utilized to sift through the pages 100 entries at a time. Since there is no database attribute telling you how long the database is, you have to go through the pages in order until reaching the end in order to choose a random entry. This is fine for small databases, but I have a cron job going that regularly chooses a random entry from a notion database with thousands of entries. Additionally, if I make too many calls simultaneously I risk being rate limited pretty often. Is there a better way to go about choosing a random value from a database that uses pagination? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a better way to do it right now (sadly). If your entries don't change often, think about caching the pages. Saves you a lot of execution time in your cron job. For the rate limit, if you use Node.js, you can build a rate-limited queue (3 requests/second) pretty easily with something like [bull](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull)